# fixed keyword to lock a reference type variable in memory from an unsafe context?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Below is code without using fixed when dealing with pointer type:

```
class PointRef 
{
   public int x;
}

public unsafe static void UseAndPinPoint() 
{
   PointRef pt = new PointRef { x = 5 };
   int* p = &pt.x;
   ... Use int* variable here!
   Console.WriteLine("Point is: {0}", pt);
}
```

and my textbook says it has to use fixed keyword otherwise it is possible that the unsafe context is attempting to interact with a member that is no longer accessible or has been repositioned on the heap after surviving a generational sweep.

I don't quite get it, in the example. isn't that pt always points to the referenced object(if we don't reassign pt to point to a different PointRef obejct as `pt = new PointRef { x = 1 };`), so the object will not be garbage collected until UseAndPinPoint() method finishes.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement

Comment: GC not only collects unused references but also performs the defragmentation. When GC defragments the heap it moves the instances  of reference types and updates their references so pt isn't guaranteed to point to the same location.

Comment: Seems to me from the microsoft docs that `PointRef pt` is something that might be moved (not talking about garbage collection here, about moving memory). If the memory is moved, `int* p` points to the wrong memory